# How to efficiently do operation on pandas each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I have a data frame like this--

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,22], [1,23], [1,44], [2, 33], [2, 55]], columns=['id', 'delay'])
```

```
id  delay
0   1   22
1   1   23
2   1   44
3   2   33
4   2   55
```

What I am doing is grouping by `id` and doing rolling operation on the `delay` column like below--

```py
k = [0.1, 0.5, 1]

def f(d):
    d['new_delay'] = pd.Series([0,0]).append(d['delay']).rolling(window=3).apply(lambda x: np.sum(x*k)).iloc[2:]
    return d

df.groupby(['id']).apply(f)
```

```
   id   delay   new_delay
0   1   22  22.0
1   1   23  34.0
2   1   44  57.7
3   2   33  33.0
4   2   55  71.5
```

It is working just fine but I am curious whether `.apply` on grouped data frame is vectorized or not. Since my dataset is huge, is there a better-vectorized way to do this kind of operation? Also I am curious if Python is single-threaded and I am running on CPU how pandas, numpy achieve vectorized calculation.

Comment: There are plenty of answers to this type of question on SO, including multiprocessing apply, vectorization, and the performance differences and when to use each.  Have you tried reading any of those?

Comment: @ProbhakarSarkar sorry, I misread ;)

Comment: @ProbhakarSarkar you literally ask if the apply is vectorized, and what other options there are that may be better.  There are answers to this exact question on SO, which show the performance differences between multiple approaches to very similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) for vectorized `rolling` with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
k = [0.1, 0.5, 1]

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


def f(d):
    return np.sum(rolling_window(np.append([0,0],d.to_numpy()), 3) * k, axis=1)

df['new_delay'] = df.groupby('id')['delay'].transform(f)
print (df)
   id  delay  new_delay
0   1     22       22.0
1   1     23       34.0
2   1     44       57.7
3   2     33       33.0
4   2     55       71.5
```

Comment: thanks for the response(+1), I am really picky about the `.apply()`  function since I read online that this `.apply()` function makes code slow, How is this approach different from the code I wrote, it would be great if you point out the inefficiencies.

Comment: @ProbhakarSarkar - `groupby + apply` should be changed by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), instead `rolling + apply` is used `strides`.

Comment: okay thanks a lot, is transform vectorized? I mean operations are done on many different groups in parallel?

Comment: @ProbhakarSarkar - Here not, it should be only faster way like rolling.

Comment: Okay, I will do some time check with the 2 approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Another option will be to use `np.convolve()` instead:

```
# Our function
f = lambda x: np.convolve(np.array([1,0.5,0.1]),x)[:len(x)]
# Groupby + Transform
df['new_delay'] = df.groupby('id')['delay'].transform(f)
```

Don't know if it's faster or not.

Comment: I also checked convolve, but I need to get the weighted sum in a rolling manner. Suppose I have an array [1,2,3] and k is [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1] then according to this it should be `array([0.1, 0.4, 1.1])` but what i want is first one is `1`, the second one `0.4*1 + 1*2`, then thirst one `0.2*1+0.4*2+1*3` like that

Comment: I tried with different mode, but unable to find solution.

Comment: I guess that you have not noticed that I flipped the array for that reason `[0.1,0.5,1]` -> `[1,0.5,0.1]`. If you're using numpy you can use the `fliplr` method to flip your array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with `groupby` + `rolling` and `apply` a custom function compiled using `numba`

```
def func(v):
    k = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 1])
    return np.sum(v * k[len(k) - len(v):])

(
    df.groupby('id')['delay']
    .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
    .apply(func, raw=True, engine='numba')
    .droplevel(0)
)
```

---

```
0    22.0
1    34.0
2    57.7
3    33.0
4    71.5
Name: delay, dtype: float64
```